# Поиск в BeautifulSoup4 по нескольким CSS тегам

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Всем привет. Есть такой кусок кода -

```
<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">14</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">31</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">25</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">14</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">19</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">25</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--4">31</div>
<div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--4">15</div>
```

Нужно вытащить именно текстовые значения из этого куска, т.е. числа 14, 31, 25 и т.д.
Нужно сделать поиск по двум CSS-селекторам, но я нашёл только способ с `*.select*`
Пробовал делать через

```
for index in range(1, 5): 
   item = code.select('.event__part--home' + f'.event__part--{index}')
```

Но получаю HTML текстом. Как получить именно число?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html_text ='<div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">14</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">31</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">25</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">14</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">19</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">25</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--4">31</div>\
            <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--4">15</div>'

import re
reg = re.compile('\d{2}')                           # То что я хочу извлечь из текста
new_number = list(map(int, reg.findall(html_text))) # Достаю двузначные числа, и перевожу их в integer
print(new_number)


>>> [14, 31, 25, 14, 19, 25, 31, 15]
```

Можете взять только строчку перевода в `int` -> `list(map(int,LIST))`.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato print(type(soup)) <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = [x.text for x in soup.findAll('div')]
#или
z = [x.text for x in soup.select('div')]
#или
z =[x.text for x in soup.select("div.event__part")]
```

Comment: Это уже найденный в супе кусок кода. Повторно использовать BeautifulSoup насколько оправдано?